# Send data to XDS Repository

Tags: intersystems, intersystems-ensemble

So I'm trying to figure out how much capabilities comes with Intersystems to send data to an XDS repository.  Specifically with using the basic Ensemble package (NO HSF)  Assume it's not the one Intersystems delivers, but an external XDS repository.

Is there a built-in way to send a large blob and wrap the ebRim around that blob?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see at http://www.intersystemsbenelux.com/media/media_manager/pdf/1398.pdf, Ensemble does not natively support ebRIM, but it does support XML and XML schemas.
Maybe you could assemble an XML and use that to wrap your blob content.

You can send that over whatever protocol your XDS system provides (xDBC, SOAP, file system etc). Take a look at the items listed on sections "Ensemble Interoperability" and "Ensemble Adapter and Gateway Guides" of http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20122/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls for a full list of connectivity options.

Regards,

Comment: Picked this one since it looks like this is what I'm going to do.  We already have other SOAP integration, and that's what we are using.  But it's good to know there are modules in HealthShare.

Answer (score 1):

There is healthshare foundation product which has XDS connectivity

See this good answer on google groups https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!topic/Ensemble-in-Healthcare/h7R300H68KQ

Or healthshare part of their website

Comment: Thanks you two, I was asking this specifically about Ensemble, so I clarified that.

Answer (score 0):

`HSF (HealthShare Foundation)` XDS.b connectivity for query and retrieve and also the Provide and Register Operation.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I re-read your question and have an answer for you.  I think what you are trying to say is that you have Ensemble, not HSF, and you still want to be able to send documents (XDS provide and Register).

I did some testing with the Open Source Integration mirth and stumbled across an example channel of theirs, and it is doing a provide and register with straight up SOAP calls to the end point.

Basically, build the required soap envelope accordingly, then send a PDF or document to the repository using MTOM.

This is what makes HealthShare its money, encapsulating all that manual construction of objects  that need to be sent to endpoints.

Anyway, a screenshot of the Mirth channel destination make give you an understanding:

http://www.integrationrequired.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Capture.PNG